# How to implement katib automl on object detection for hyperparameter tuning

Tags: object-detection, automl, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to implement Katib automl for object detection work for the yolov4 and yolov8 model.

Comment: please share more details including what you have done so far including source code and errors faced